# Measure of null (or full) subsets of manifolds and absolute continuity of smooth measures

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry

It is common to define null (resp. full) subsets of a $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ in the following way: $A \subseteq M$ is a null subset if its preimage under every coordinate chart is a null (resp. full) subset of the chart's domain (which is an open subset of the Cartesian space $\mathbb{R}^n$) under the Lebesgue measure.

Consider a smooth measure $\mu$ on $M$, i.e. $\mu$ is induced from a volume form or a density of $M$, and assume that $A \subseteq M$ is a null subset in the sense of the previous definition, must we have $\mu(A) = 0$? (resp. question for full $\mu$-measure).

Related question: if $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are smooth measures on $M$, do they have to be mutually absolutely continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\rho$ be a non-negative smooth scalar density on $M$, and $\mu$ the associated measure. Recall that this means (almost by definition) that given any chart $(U,\alpha)$ on $M$ and any Lebesgue-measurable subset $A\subset M$, we have
\begin{align}
\mu(A\cap U)&=\int_{\alpha[A\cap U]}\rho_{\alpha}(x)\,d\lambda_n(x)\tag{$*$},
\end{align}
where $\rho_{\alpha}:\alpha[U]\to (0,\infty)$ is the local coordinate expression of the density and $\lambda_n$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^n$. More succinctly, this says that on $\alpha[U]$, we have $\frac{d(\alpha_*\mu)}{d\lambda_n}=\rho_{\alpha}$, or equivalently that when restricted to $U$, we have $\frac{d\mu}{d(\alpha^*\lambda_n)}= \rho_{\alpha}\circ \alpha$ (where $\alpha_*$ denotes pushforward of measures, and $\alpha^*=(\alpha^{-1})_*$ is the pullback of measures).

With this in mind, the first definition of null implies the second. To justify this, fix an at-most countable atlas $\{(U_i,\alpha_i)\}$ of $M$, and suppose $A$ is a null set in the sense of the first definition. Then for each index $i$, we have $\mu(A\cap U_i)=\int_{\alpha_i[A\cap U_i]}\rho_{\alpha_i}\,d\lambda_n=0$, since we're integrating a non-negative function over a set of Lebesgue measure zero. Therefore (countable subadditivity of measures), $\mu(A)\leq \sum_{i}\mu(A\cap U_i)=0$.

The converse is true if we assume $\rho$ is a **strictly positive** density. In this case, if $\mu(A)=0$, then for any chart $(U,\alpha)$ of $M$, we have by monotonicity of measures, $0=\mu(A\cap U)=\int_{\alpha[A\cap U]}\rho_{\alpha}\,d\lambda_n$; and since $\rho_{\alpha}$ is a strictly positive function, we have $\lambda_n(\alpha[A\cap U])=0$, thereby recovering the first definition.

The analogous statements for full measure can be obtained from the above statements by taking complements (after all a set is defined to have full measure if its complement has measure zero).

For the final question, we have the following theorem:

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $\rho_1,\rho_2$ smooth non-negative densities on $M$, and $\mu_1,\mu_2$ their associated measures. If $\rho_2$ is strictly positive, then $\mu_1\ll\mu_2$, and the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\mu_1}{d\mu_2}:M\to \Bbb{R}$ is a smooth non-negative function such that for any coordinate chart $(U,\alpha)$, we have
> \begin{align}
> \frac{d\mu_1}{d\mu_2}\bigg|_U &=\left(\frac{\rho_{1,\alpha}}{\rho_{2,\alpha}}\right)\circ \alpha.
> \end{align}

The proof is pretty simple. If $\mu_2(A)=0$, then because $\rho_2$ is assumed strictly positive, we have that $A$ is a null set in the sense of the first definition, and hence $\mu_1(A)=0$ (because $\rho_1$ is a non-negative density). This shows $\mu_1\ll\mu_2$, and hence, by the Radon-Nikodym theorem, the derivative $\frac{d\mu_1}{d\mu_2}$ exists.

However, in this specific case, we do not have to appeal to the Radon-Nikodym theorem to assert the existence of the derivative; we can actually proceed directly.  If we fix a chart $(U,\alpha)$, then the definition $(*)$ above shows tells us that $\frac{d\mu_1}{d(\alpha^*\lambda_n)}=\rho_{1,\alpha}\circ \alpha$ and $\frac{d\mu_2}{d(\alpha^*\lambda_n)}=\rho_{2,\alpha}\circ \alpha$. Now hopefully you've justified the 'chain rule' for Radon-Nikodym-derivatives, because from this it follows $\frac{d\mu_1}{d\mu_2}\bigg|_U=\frac{\rho_{1,\alpha}}{\rho_{2,\alpha}}\circ \alpha$ (and from this explicit formula, we know the Radon-Nikodym derivative is smooth and non-negative).

Finally, if you assume the two densities $\rho_1,\rho_2$ are strictly positive (which is the case if the densities are induced by a non-degenerate $(0,2)$-tensor field on the manifold, e.g. from a (pseudo-)Riemannian metric, or a symplectic form), then applying the theorem above twice, we see that the induced measures are mutually absolutely continuous, and the Radon-Nikodym derivatives are as obvious as it can get.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a reference for this and/or related topics?

Comment: @maxbo I've pieced this stuff together from various books, e.g Loomis and Sternberg's *Advanced Calculus*, Chapter 10, Amann and Escher's *Analysis III* and Dieudonne's *Treatise on Analysis Vol III*, section 16.20-16.24. Loomis talks about densities but not measures (they only introduced the theory of content rather than measures), but the ideas are essentially there. Amann and Escher do talk about how a measure is induced from a Riemannian metric (and other basic facts), and Dieudonne also goes over carefully how to transport Lebesgue integration and measures to manifolds.

Comment: but I don't think I've seen any one source which states and proves the absolute continuity; it's one of those facts which I've heard about, and I just worked out the details one day. (For example, it's also a good idea to work out, given densities on two manifolds, and the associated measures, how one can induce corresponding densities and measures on the product manifold $M\times N$ and other basic stuff like this).